# How to select user input from a shell script in PHP?

Tags: php, bash

I've this shell script running from a PHP site.

In the shell script (Audit shell script), 
I have 3 options:

1) Process script
2) Display results 
3) Exit

Tried the codes below and doesn't seem to work, the PHP site displayed blanks.

```
<?php



session_start();


exec('/Desktop/test.sh');
exec('1');
$output = exec('2');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you write "doesn't seem to work", only you know "what" didn't work.. Instead, you need to write, what you expected and what else came in the output.

Comment: Ok, when an user inputs "1" in the shell script, results will be push into a file named results.txt. When the user inputs "2", results.txt will be displayed. How do i make that results.txt display??

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  session_start();

  // This line executes '/Desktop/test.sh' as if it had been called from the
  // command line
  // exec('/Desktop/test.sh');

  // This line attempts to execute a file called '1', which would have to be
  // in the same directory as this script
  // exec('1');

  // This line attempts to execute a file called '2', which would have to be
  // in the same directory as this script, and capture the first line of the
  // output in $output
  // $output = exec('2');

  // I think you want to be doing something more like this - this executes the
  // shell script, passing "1" and "2" as arguments, and captures the whole
  // output as an array in $output
  exec('/Desktop/test.sh "1" "2"', $output);

  // Loop the output array and echo it to the browser
  echo "<pre>";
  foreach ($output as $lineno => $line) echo "Line $lineno: $line\n";
  echo "</pre>";

?>
```

It seems to me that you could do with reading the [manual page for `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) properly...

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what i meant. I tried your codes and the browser still displayed blanks. Am a total newbie in php, sorry for that.

Comment: Are you sure the command you are running actually outputs something? What do you get if you type `/Desktop/test.sh "1" "2"` in a terminal? What does your `.sh` script contain?

Comment: When i input option "1", it will create a file named "result.txt". However, when i tried "/Desktop/test.sh "1"" in a terminal, my result.txt is not created. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you edit the question with the code from `/Desktop/test.sh`? Also, what is the **full** path of your PHP script, and the **full** path of `test.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using proc_open instead of exec; it gives you more control of process input/output.  Something like:

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"), // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"), // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/dev/null", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/Desktop';
$env = array();

$process = proc_open('/Desktop/test.sh', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be sent to /dev/null (ie, discarded)

    fwrite($pipes[0], "1\n");
    fwrite($pipes[0], "2\n");
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    $output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo $output;
}

?>
```

Note:  I've lifted this code from the [PHP Manual's proc_open page](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)