# Bash interaction with web page

Tags: php, bash

I've adopted the php **shell_exec** approach given in the answer to my previous SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265749/bash-script-callable-from-web-page/20265891?noredirect=1#20265891). The next issue is how I get the php and the script to work together so as to give the user the chance to enter the text. What should happen is the user is prompted to enter a string and then press the Enter key to signify the string is complete. The script then prompts for the next string, the user does so and presses the Enter key, and so on until all required strings are input. At the moment my HTML is very bare:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>Email address builder</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$output = shell_exec('bash /var/www/addressbuilder');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter first initial and press [ENTER]: "
read initial
echo "Enter first name in full and press [ENTER]: "
read firstname
echo "Enter surname and press [ENTER]: "
read surname
echo "Enter email domain and press [ENTER]: "
read domain

at='@'
semicolon=';'
fulldomain=$at$domain

variant1=$firstname$fulldomain
variant2=$initial$surname$fulldomain

echo $variant1$semicolon$variant2
```

How do I get php to provide the interactivity I need to work with the script?

Comment: You need to understand WHO is executor of PHP code ? it's webserver: apache, nginx or other. The user you mentioned can only see the result output through webserver. So user can't provide input this way, Build a html form and do HTTP POST or GET should work.

Comment: I didn't know you can execute a directory?!

Comment: @DarylGill: addressbuilder is the name of the file, not the directory.   It works, i.e. bash does process the script.

Comment: This seems like a fair amount of effort for a simple script. Is there a reason you can't port the bash script to PHP?

Comment: @Jim - no reason other than I'd need to learn the basics of PHP which I've so far managed to resist :). I may need to do that though.

Comment: @ClivevanHilten Does this link help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633453/how-to-select-user-input-from-a-shell-script-in-php

Comment: @Jim thanks for the link - I can get the bash script output to display on the web page fine, but (as Fwolf said above) the issue is that there's no way (unless I use PHP or some similar scripting language) to get the user input into the bash script.